# Building a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree

I have an outline format text document that can have up to 6 levels.

```
.step1 -- step 1. text
..step2 -- step 1. A. text
..step2 -- step 1. B. text
..step2 -- step 1. C. text
..step2 -- step 1. D. text
..step2 -- step 1. E. text
.step1 -- step 2. text
..step2 -- step 2. A. text
...step3 -- step 2. A. (1) text
...step3 -- step 2. A. (2) text
.step1 -- step 3. text
```

I'm parsing the text document with regex and building an array that is structured like this

```
$contentsArray structure
    'level' INT - the step level
    'type'  STRING - the type of tag, note, warning, step1, step2
    'line'  INT - the line number in the file
    'text'  STRING - the text

 ------ SAMPLE ARRAY -------

   [0] => Array
    (
        [level] => 1
        [type] => step1
        [line] => 8
        [text] => Step 1. text
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [type] => step2
        [line] => 10
        [text] => Step 1. A. text
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [type] => step2
        [line] => 12
        [text] => Step 1.B. text
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [type] => step2
        [line] => 14
        [text] => Step 1. C. text.
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [type] => step2
        [line] => 16
        [text] => Step 1. D. text.
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [type] => step2
        [line] => 18
        [text] => Step 1. E. text.
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [level] => 1
        [type] => step1
        [line] => 20
        [text] => Step 2. text
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [type] => step2
        [line] => 22
        [text] => Step 2. A. Text.
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [level] => 3
        [type] => step3
        [line] => 26
        [text] => Step 2. A. (1) Text.
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [level] => 3
        [type] => step3
        [line] => 28
        [text] => Step 3. A. (2) Text.
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [level] => 1
        [type] => step1
        [line] => 30
        [text] => Step 3. Text
    )
```

The end goal is to turn this into a nested XML document.

```
<step1>Step 1. text
   <step2>Step 1. A. text</step2>
   <step2>Step 1. B. text</step2>
   <step2>Step 1. C. text</step2>
   <step2>Step 1. D. text</step2>
   <step2>Step 1. E. text</step2>
</step1>
<step1>Step 2. text
   <step2>Step 2. A. text
     <step3>Step 2. A. (1) text</step3>
     <step3>Step 2. A. (2) text</step3>
   </step2>
</step1>
<step1>Step 3. text
</step1>
```

I think that what I need is to build a nested array that I can then convert into the XML. I think the structure for this array would be something like

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
            [type] => step1
            [line] => 8
            [text] => Step 1. text
        ), Array
            (
                [level] => 2
                [type] => step2
                [line] => 10
                [text] => Step 1. A. text
            ), Array
            (
                [level] => 2
                [type] => step2
                [line] => 12
                [text] => Step 1.B. text
            ), Array
            (
                [level] => 2
                [type] => step2
                [line] => 14
                [text] => Step 1. C. text.
            ), Array
            (
                [level] => 2
                [type] => step2
                [line] => 16
                [text] => Step 1. D. text.
            ), Array
            (
                [level] => 2
                [type] => step2
                [line] => 18
                [text] => Step 1. E. text.
            )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
            [type] => step1
            [line] => 20
            [text] => Step 2. text
        , Array
            (
                [level] => 2
                [type] => step2
                [line] => 22
                [text] => Step 2. A. Text.
                , Array
                (
                    [level] => 3
                    [type] => step3
                    [line] => 26
                    [text] => Step 2. A. (1) Text.
                ), Array
                (
                    [level] => 3
                    [type] => step3
                    [line] => 28
                    [text] => Step 3. A. (2) Text.
                )
            )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
            [type] => step1
            [line] => 30
            [text] => Step 3. Text
        )
```

What I need is some help on a method to loop through the array that I have built and use the `level` value to figure out the nesting in the final array. My attempts have been pretty fruitless to this point. I feel like there is a recursive or iterator way to do this but these aren't my strong suit.

Thanks for the help and I hope this question is clear enough.

**UPDATE THE QUESTION** I see I did a pretty poor job of asking the question so I have made some edits.

Comment: If you're using PHP you should tag the question with 'php' tag

Comment: I am doing this in PHP but to me this is more of a technique question.

Comment: You describe an associative array with 4 properties, but where is the "text" part in your input, and how come your array just has a "text" property and not the other 3?

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't consistent. Assuming the last `...step3` is a mistake, this will do what you want. It's in perl, but should easily translate.

```
sub main {
  my @labels;
  while (<>) {
    if (/^(\.+)(.*)$/) {
      my $level = length($1);
      print "</" . pop(@labels) . ">\n" while $level <= scalar(@labels);
      die "Bad input" unless $level == 1 + scalar(@labels);
      print "<" . $2 . ">\n";
      push @labels, $2
    }
  }
  print "</" . pop(@labels) . ">\n" while (@labels);
}

main;
```

It's using a simple stack and processing level changes with respect to current stack size.

I'll let you work out the indentation. You can do this based on stack size, too.

**Addition**

Well, you've changed the question quite a bit. But the basic approach of using a stack and processing level changes with respect to stack length will still work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is PHP implementation for when you have the input text in a variable `$input`:

```
$stack = [];
foreach(explode("\n", $input . "\n.") as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    $type = ltrim($line, ".");
    $dots = strlen($line) - strlen($type);
    if (!$dots || $dots > count($stack) + 1) throw new Exception("Bad input format");
    while($dots <= count($stack)) 
        $xml[] = str_repeat("    ", count($stack)-1) . array_pop($stack);
    $xml[] = str_repeat("    ", count($stack)) . "<$type>";
    $stack[] = "</$type>";
}
$xml = implode("\n", array_slice($xml, 0, -1));
echo $xml;
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/801831).